# How to create a Table in Python using values from a Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, row

I'm using Python and I have a dictionary with multiples lists in it, and each list has exactly 5 elements in it.

What I would like to do is to print a nice looking table with only the elements in the lists inside the dictionary, without any of the keys. The problem is because of the different lenght of each element on the list, it prints out a very bad looking table.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there example dictionary, expected output and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I assume you want some thing like this:

```
{
  1: [512, 512, 512, 512, 512], 
  2: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
  3: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
}
```

to be printed as:

```
 512  2  20
 512  2  20
 512  2  20
 512  2  20
 512  2  20
```

You can use pandas module to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

a={
  1: [512, 512, 512, 512, 512], 
  2: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
  3: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
}

b = pd.DataFrame(a)  # create a dataframe from dictionary
b.columns = ['' for _ in range(len(b.columns))]  # replace column names(keys) with empty string
print(b.to_string(index=False)) # print dataframe as table but hide row indices
```

Edit:
to print key as row you can use the transpose function as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

a={
  1: [512, 512, 512, 512, 512], 
  2: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
  3: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
}

b = pd.DataFrame(a)  # create a dataframe from dictionary
b = b.T # get transpose of  b and save to b
b.columns = ['' for _ in range(len(b.columns))]  # replace column names(keys) with empty string
print(b.to_string(index=False)) # print dataframe as table but hide row indices
```

output should be:

```
 512  512  512  512  512
   2    2    2    2    2
  20   20   20   20   20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It worked perfectly and with your comments I could understand it. Is there a way to do that but instead of printing a key as column, print it as a row?